# How to setup custom submain for Api Gateway for site managed by wix?

Tags: dns, subdomain, aws-api-gateway

Our website mywebsite.com is currently managed by Wix DNS. We wanted to create a subdomain api.mywebsite.com to forward requests to aws api gateway. Here are the steps I tried

1. Created an ACM certificate for *.mywebsite.com
2. In AWS console API gateway I created a custom domain and associated it with ACM certificated I created about. I got a cloudfront target domain name somecloudfrontid.cloudfront.net
3. I created a CNAME record in wix that points api.mywebsite.com to somecloudfrontid.cloudfront.net.

But, when I tried to hit api.mywebsite.com I get this error:

> ERROR
>
> The request could not be satisfied.
>
> Bad request.  Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)

Am I missing any step? How can I get this working? Do I need to transfer my domain to AWS router 53 to make it work with AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest transferring the domain to Route53. There you can create an alias for your subdomain under Hosted Zones, and point it directly to your cloudfront target domain, as well as several other AWS resources quite easily.